# NSDocument-based app, open dialog with 'New Document' button on launch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dialog, nsdocument, textedit

TextEdit and Pixelmator both open an open-file-dialog on launch that has a 'New Document' button in the bottom left corner.

Is there any particular code available to achieve the very same effect?

The reason I ask is that Pixelmator's way of going about it, the 'New Document' button included, is exactly the same as TextEdit, and I figure there must be some simple way to achieve this but I must be missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turns out you need to enable iCloud.](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-implement-the-%C2%93new-document%C2%94-window-like-pages-app-does.1751451/)

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding an empty accessoryView to the openPanel also makes the "New Document" button visible. To do this, in your NSDocumentController descendant override beginPanel:forTypes:completionHandler: for example like below

```
- (void)beginOpenPanel:(NSOpenPanel*)openPanel forTypes:(NSArray<NSString*>*)inTypes completionHandler:(void(^)(NSInteger result))completionHandler {
    // adding any accessory view makes the "New Document" button visible.
    NSView* workaround = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    openPanel.accessoryView = workaround;
    // for non-arc: [workaround release];
    [super beginOpenPanel:openPanel forTypes:inTypes completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        openPanel.accessoryView = nil;
        completionHandler(result);
    }];
}
```

You'll get warnings like this in the log:

```
[Layout] The Open/Save panel was supplied an accessory view with bad layout constraints, resulting in a view that is zero width. ...
```

I have not found a way to avoid that, but at least the New Document button is visible and working OK.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works in MacOS Sonoma: it causes the OpenPanel to crash the app